# Boost::python: Converting a C++ set<string> to a Python list

Tags: python, c++, boost

AFAICS the following converter should convert a C++ set to a Python list, but it segfaults; any help would be much appreciated.

```
struct set_string_to_python_list
// boost::python::set doesn't exist, so we convert to a Python list
{
    static PyObject* convert(set<string> const& s)
    {
        boost::python::list result;
        for(const string& str : s)
            result.append(boost::python::object(s));
        return incref(result.ptr());
    }
};
```

I can provide a minimum compilable example if useful.

Comment: Where does it segfault?

Comment: Hard to tell. As soon as I add a print statement the segfault goes away.

Comment: It looks like some object is destroyed prematurely. Not necessarily one you have in this function. You can try to use valgrind or the address sanitizer to try and catch this. Otherwise set breakpoints in all relevant destructors and see if you can catch something.